# Is this a simple proof that gas pressure is a relativistic invariant?

Tags: thermodynamics, special-relativity, pressure, inertial-frames, gas

This is a simple thought experiment that hopefully demonstrates that gas pressure is an invariant in relativity.

Consider two very long sealed rectangular boxes that contain equal gas pressure when at rest in the same reference frame. A flexible hose connects the two boxes. One of the boxes (A) remains at rest and the other (B) is accelerated to a significant velocity relative and appears to length contract in the reference frame of A. If we assume the gas inside the box B has become compressed by the length contraction, the gas would be at greater pressure than the gas in A and the gas would flow through the pipe from B to A. Now if we switch reference frames to the rest frame of B, it is now box A that appears to be length contracted and by the same logic the gas in box A would be compressed and gas would flow through the pipe to box B. Obviously this would be a contradiction, because the nett gas flow cannot be in both directions at the same time, so we have to conclude the gas pressure remains constant in both boxes.

The flexible hose is a complication because parts of the hose are moving in different directions at the same time. It can be removed by having the two boxes slide alongside each other with holes in the sides of the (frictionless) sliding faces that briefly align with each other, allowing the gases to pass from one box to the other if required. Does this work?

Comment: Interesting question. I am going to think it over, maybe try it out, and come back and check here. If it were me, I would use the classical "ideal gas statistical mechanics" type argument, where the pressure is the  effect of all the collisions against the wall, and you get pressure, density, and RMS velocity all proportional to each other (obviously RMS velocity is the internal energy which is the temperature, and so you get the ideal gas law). If you then do all the regular Lorentz transformations on the gas particles and the wall of the container, you should get an invariant pressure.

Comment: @PoissonAerohead I did all the calculations years ago, using classical gas laws and momentum imparted to a surface area by particles in the relativistic context and did all the transformations etc, and came to the same conclusion. The response was ..hmm.... maybe... This thought experiment seems much simpler and harder to deny.

Comment: I cannot make much sense of it, what is the cm of box B moves away at a way larger speed than the average velocity of the molecules in the cm of B? then very few molecules would crash against whatever wall/piston that  separates the two gases.

Comment: @PatoGalmarini When I did the calculations (years ago) I was assuming that after the acceleration phase the molecules in the gas collide with the rear wall of the accelerated box, which imparts additional forward momentum to the gas molecules which spreads through the gas giving it a new equilibrium where the average velocity of the gas particles and their cm is comoving with the box, before the holes coincide. A bit like the the air in a car settles down to comoving with the car after rapid acceleration, once it reached constant velocity .

Answer (score 0):

From the comment thread below the question, it seems that you have calculated the result previously using the correct methods and were wondering whether this thought experiment provided an intuitive proof.

I would agree with Pato Galmarini that it is difficult to interpret the thought experiment. If the gasses are separating, there is a reduction in velocity, and if they are approaching, then there is an increase. This will change what is seen as pressure for the same reason there is drag on a bluff body in a fluid flow. Also, your second option will still lead to a shearing between them, because there is a bias to the momentum in the direction of motion of the gas container, and that will be transported across the interface.

The right way to do it is the way I suggested, which you say you have already done. It is very difficult to come up with a sensible design for the thought experiment you are proposing, one that actually solves the issue of interfacing two containers of gas moving relative to each other in a way that "totally cancels the motion" so that you can show that the static pressure must be identical.